# converting insert into to select

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, sql

I have a file with the following format

```
INSERT INTO table1(field1,field2,field3) VALUES('values1','value2','value3');
INSERT INTO table1(field1,field2,field3) VALUES('other_values1','other_value2','other_value3');
INSERT INTO table1(field1,field2,field3) VALUES('another_values1','another_value2','another_value3');
INSERT INTO table2(table2_field1,table2_field2,table2_field3,field4) VALUES('table2_values1','table2_value2','table2_value3');
INSERT INTO table2(table2_field1,table2_field2,table2_field3,table2_field4) VALUES('other_table2_values1','other_table2_value2','other_table2_value3');
INSERT INTO table2(table2_field1,table2_field2,table2_field3,table2_field4) VALUES('another_table2_values1','another_table2_value2','another_table2_value3','another_table2_value4');
```

I want this output

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1='values1' AND field2='values2' AND field3=='values3';
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1='other_values1' AND field2='other_values2' AND field3=='other_values3';
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1='another_values1' AND field2='another_values2' AND field3=='another_values3';
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2_field1='table2_values1' AND table2_field2='table2_values2' AND table2_field3=='table2_values3' AND table2_field4=='table2_values4';
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2_field1='table2_values1' AND table2_field2='table2_values2' AND table2_field3=='table2_values3' AND table2_field4=='table2_values4';
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2_field1='table2_values1' AND table2_field2='table2_values2' AND table2_field3=='table2_values3' AND table2_field4=='table2_values4';
```

What I've done so far is

```
cat test_inserts |awk -F '[()]' '{print $1 " WHERE "$2 $4}' |sed 's/INSERT INTO /SELECT * FROM /g'
```

and it gives me the following output

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1,field2,field3'values1','value2','value3'
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1,field2,field3'other_values1','other_value2','other_value3'
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1,field2,field3'another_values1','another_value2','another_value3'
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2_field1,table2_field2,table2_field3,field4'table2_values1','table2_value2','table2_value3'
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2_field1,table2_field2,table2_field3,table2_field4'other_table2_values1','other_table2_value2','other_table2_value3'
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2_field1,table2_field2,table2_field3,table2_field4'another_table2_values1','another_table2_value2','another_table2_value3','another_table2_value4'
```

Comment: Don't `cat file | awk 'stuff'`; just `awk 'stuff' file`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Complex **`AWK`** solution:

```
awk -F'[()]' '{ sub(/INSERT INTO */,"",$1); 
                printf "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE ",$1;
                len=split($2, f, ","); split($4, v, ","); 
                for (i=1; i<=len; i++) printf "%s=%s%s", f[i], v[i], (i==len? ";":" AND ");
                print "" 
              }' test_inserts
```

- `-F'[()]'` - complex field separator
- `sub(/INSERT INTO */,"",$1)` - remove `INSERT INTO` phrase from the 1st field (to extract a *table* name)
- `printf "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE ",$1` - print the start of SQL statement containing a *table* name
- `split($2, f, ",")` - split the 2nd field by separator `,` to obtain field ***names*** (`f` becomes an array of field names)
- `split($4, v, ",")` - split the 4th field by separator `,` to obtain field ***values*** (`v` becomes an array of field values)

---

The output:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1='values1' AND field2='value2' AND field3='value3';
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1='other_values1' AND field2='other_value2' AND field3='other_value3';
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1='another_values1' AND field2='another_value2' AND field3='another_value3';
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2_field1='table2_values1' AND table2_field2='table2_value2' AND table2_field3='table2_value3' AND field4=;
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2_field1='other_table2_values1' AND table2_field2='other_table2_value2' AND table2_field3='other_table2_value3' AND table2_field4=;
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2_field1='another_table2_values1' AND table2_field2='another_table2_value2' AND table2_field3='another_table2_value3' AND table2_field4='another_table2_value4';
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative in Python, in case you're into that sort of thing (more verbose but more legible than `awk`, at least for me):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
"""transform_query.py"""

import sys
import re

# Open the data file specified by the user
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as query_file:
    for row in query_file.readlines():

        # Regular expression to extract table name, field names, and values from each line
        match = re.search(
            r'^INSERT INTO '
                r'(?P<table>table\d+)\((?P<fields>[\w,]+)\) '
                r'VALUES\((?P<values>[^()]+)\);$',
            row.strip()
        )
        if match:

            # Store the table name (not necessary)
            table = match.group('table')

            # Split the fields string into a list
            fields = match.group('fields').split(',')

            # Split the values string into a list
            values = match.group('values').split(',')

            # Recombine the strings into a SELECT statement
            # and print the result
            print(
                "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {};".format(
                    table,
                    ' AND '.join(
                        ['='.join([field, value]) for field, value in zip(fields, values)]
                    ),
                )
            )
```

Run it:

```bsh
python transform_query.py query.sql
```

And here's the output:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1='values1' AND field2='value2' AND field3='value3';
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1='other_values1' AND field2='other_value2' AND field3='other_value3';
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1='another_values1' AND field2='another_value2' AND field3='another_value3';
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2_field1='table2_values1' AND table2_field2='table2_value2' AND table2_field3='table2_value3';
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2_field1='other_table2_values1' AND table2_field2='other_table2_value2' AND table2_field3='other_table2_value3';
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2_field1='another_table2_values1' AND table2_field2='another_table2_value2' AND table2_field3='another_table2_value3' AND table2_field4='another_table2_value4';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are needing explanation, tell me and I will add comments into the code.

**Requirements:**

1. The number of fields and values should match.
2. Field names and field values should not contain these characters: `,)(;` - comma, parentheses, semicolon.

---

```
gawk '{
    num = patsplit($3$4, arr, /[^,)(;]+/);
    num /= 2;

    printf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE ", arr[1]);

    for(i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
        printf("%s=%s", arr[i], arr[num + i]);

        printf (i < num) ? " AND " : ";\n";
    }
}' input.txt
```

**Explanation:**

This string is picked as example: `INSERT INTO table1(field1,field2,field3) VALUES('values1','value2','value3');`

1. `num = patsplit($3$4, arr, /[^,)(;]+/);`

   - `patsplit(s, a, r)` - split  the  string  **s** into the array **a** on the regular expression **r**, and return the number of fields.
   - `$3$4` - `$3` is `table1(field1,field2,field3)`, `$4` is `VALUES('values1','value2','value3');`. So, after concatenating, we have this string: `table1(field1,field2,field3)VALUES('values1','value2','value3');`.
   - then, split it to `arr` by this regex `/[^,)(;]+/`. It means: all characters, except comma, parentheses, semicolon. Therefore now: `arr[1]` is `table1`, `arr[2]` is `field1`, `arr[5]` is `VALUES`, so on.
2. `num /= 2;` for algorithm used in this script, the half of the `num` variable is needed.
3. `printf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE ", arr[1]);` - print the first element of the `arr`, which is the table name. In our case, it is the `table1`.
4. `printf("%s=%s", arr[i], arr[num + i]);` - the algorithm. Print one element from the first half of the `arr` and corresponding element from the second half of the `arr`. That is, `arr[2]` and `arr[6]`, `arr[3]` and `arr[7]`, `arr[4]` and `arr[8]`.
5. `printf (i < num) ? " AND " : ";\n";` - The ternary operator. If it is not the last iteration, print `AND`, else print `;\n` (final semicolon and newline).

**Input** (I corrected your input, because it had errors - the number of field names and field values didn't match).

```
INSERT INTO table1(field1,field2,field3) VALUES('values1','value2','value3');
INSERT INTO table1(field1,field2,field3) VALUES('other_values1','other_value2','other_value3');
INSERT INTO table1(field1,field2,field3) VALUES('another_values1','another_value2','another_value3');
INSERT INTO table2(table2_field1,table2_field2,table2_field3,table2_field4) VALUES('table2_values1','table2_value2','table2_value3','table2_value4');
INSERT INTO table2(table2_field1,table2_field2,table2_field3,table2_field4) VALUES('other_table2_values1','other_table2_value2','other_table2_value3','other_table2_value4');
INSERT INTO table2(table2_field1,table2_field2,table2_field3,table2_field4) VALUES('another_table2_values1','another_table2_value2','another_table2_value3','another_table2_value4');
```

**Output**

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1='values1' AND field2='value2' AND field3='value3';
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1='other_values1' AND field2='other_value2' AND field3='other_value3';
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1='another_values1' AND field2='another_value2' AND field3='another_value3';
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2_field1='table2_values1' AND table2_field2='table2_value2' AND table2_field3='table2_value3' AND table2_field4='table2_value4';
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2_field1='other_table2_values1' AND table2_field2='other_table2_value2' AND table2_field3='other_table2_value3' AND table2_field4='other_table2_value4';
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2_field1='another_table2_values1' AND table2_field2='another_table2_value2' AND table2_field3='another_table2_value3' AND table2_field4='another_table2_value4';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and yes you can add an explanation, it's useful for me and other users.

Comment: Note that **patsplit()** makes this dependent on GNU awk, and won't work for BSD's "One True" awk (at least FreeBSD).

Comment: @user3333911 Explanation added.